CloudWatch Logs Insights Query to Calculate hoursAgo Field Returning Incorrect Values
fields 
toMillis(now()) as now,
toMillis(@timestamp) as Timestamp,
@timestamp, 
(toMillis(now()) - toMillis(@timestamp)) / (1000 * 60 * 60) as hoursAgo, 
Properties.SourceContext, Properties.LogEntry.Message, MessageTemplate, Properties.Guid, 
@message, @logStream, @log
| sort @timestamp desc 
| limit 500 


The hoursAgo field shows negative values. Should I convert the timestamps to bigint or adjust the calculation?
